# using google api explorer to upload data to google cloud storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, client-library

i am trying to use google api explorer to first try to insert an object to google cloud storage.

the request looks like

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/visionapibucket/o?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "contentType": "image/jpeg",
 "uploadType": "media",
 "path": "/upload/storage/v1/b/visionapibucket/o"
}
```

but i see the error as

```
400 HTTP/2.0 400

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required"
   },
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "wrongUrlForUpload",
    "message": "Upload requests must include an uploadType URL parameter and a URL path beginning with /upload/",
    "extendedHelp": "https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required"
 }
}
```

not sure what i am missing. please advise

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug on the website. It doesn't seem like the explorer supports media.

The request it generated looks like:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/visionapibucket/o?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

But a proper upload request would look like:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/visionapibucket/o?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&uploadType=media&name=myfile.jpeg
```

You'll also want to include a "Content-Type" header specifying that it's a JPEG image.

There's [a guide on the various ways to upload objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload) using the JSON API here. The specific type you're looking for is like a [simple upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/simple-upload).

Comment: irony is i m not able to see a working solution that can upload an image via javascript using gapi. documentation is completely useless in terms of an example that  works